# "Расчирикал попугай" - можно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно сказать ***"попугай расчирикал что-то"***?

Answer (score 1):

> можно сказать "попугай расчирикал"?

.

Можно или так: *попугай **зачирикал***.

Или так:  *попугай **расчирикался***.

Comment: тут расчирикал типа разболтал....а не просто, как зачирикал...

Comment: @ flossyU: _тут **расчирикал** типа **разболтал**_... Ну, если _**расчирикал о чём-то кому-то**_, то тогда, наверное, такая форма возможна. Лучше было бы привести предложение полностью.

Comment: Лучше "расщебетался" (не воробей ведь), в "прикладном" смысле можно "расщебетал" (что-то кому-то); "расчирикал" звучит излишне парадоксально.

Comment: ))расчирикал жене о неверном муже....

Comment: _))расчирикал жене о неверном муже...._ === Лучше было бы привести предложение полностью.

Comment: @Alex_ander, знаете, может, я и ошибаюсь, но мне кажется, что "щебетать" (и производные от него) очень плохо ассоциируется с целенаправленным действием (разболтать), хуже, чем "чирикать".

Comment: У меня слово "чирикать" в рамках мира птиц твёрдо ассоциируется с воробьиным копирайтом (воробей как бы "в законе", а остальные мелкие "щебечут" при передаче информации, "прощебетать" могут и т. п.), а к людям его вполне можно относить без ограничений  :)

Comment: Согласен со всем. Насчёт людей понравилось.)) Но вот для меня "прощебетать" звучит да, вполне хорошо, а "**рас**щебетать" как-то не очень... Но что "расчирикал" к попугаю сложно отнести, согласен и даже не знаю, что предложить ещё...

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: попугай расчирикался.

РАСЧИРИКАТЬСЯ,  св. Разг. 1. Издать звуки чириканья (обычно о воробьях, синицах). 2. Разговориться (обычно шумно, галдя). Дети в своей комнате опять расчирикались.

РАСЧИРИКАТЬ, св. что. Разг. Исчеркать, исписать бумагу чертами, линиями, пометами и т. п. (обычно небрежно, размашисто). Р. всю контрольную работу.

Чирикать ― расчирикаться,  формант РАС + СЯ указывает на интенсивность действия, совершаемое субъектом.

**Расчирикать (что-то)  ― разболтать,** вполне возможный авторский вариант, например:

[**Текст песни «Воробьиная песенка»**](http://x-minus.org/track/274779/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)

С ним мы делимся обедом,
Как положено друзьям.
**Расчирикал** он об этом
Всем знакомым воробьям.

Я им крошек дам послаще.
И недели не пройдёт ―
Все увидят настоящий
Воробьиный хоровод.

Answer (score 0):

Я так и не поняла, что следует из всего уже сказанного.

Формулирую. Сказать так **можно**. Но только если автор имеет в виду что попугай "разболтал" какую-то новость или тайну. Ну и при этом надо понимать, что слово "расчирикал" будет использовано в необычно, авторском значении.